# Power BI DirectQuery mode - "Couldn't load the model schema". But able to do transformations in Query editor

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to connect to a SQL server DB via Power BI Desktop. The connection mode selected is **DirectQuery** . I am able to establish the connection to the SQL db. But in the report viewer i don't see the table loaded. And i keep getting this popup saying - ***Unexpected error. Couldn't load the model schema***.

But when i open the query editor, i am able to see the table contents and do some transformations. But when trying to load it doesn't come up in the report viewer *Fields* pane on the right. Again get this error- Couldn't load the model schema.

I have tried the resolution related to windows defender. But get that -resetplatform is not an valid option.

> Users can work around this issue by running the following command from
>   an elevated command prompt: "C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Defender\MpCmdRun.exe –resetplatform"

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone, this is how i solved it.
When trying to connect to SQL server from PBI desktop, skip giving the port number in the server input box. Although the tool tip mentions u can enter as ***server:port***.

By connecting this way, i was able to load the model both in report viewer as well as see data and transform on Query editor.

A very trivial issue. but took quite a while to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on my Windows 7 machine. I then installed the latest Power BI version (Version: 2.62.5222.761 64-bit (September 2018)) from the Microsoft store on my Windows 10 machine. Surprisingly, it worked there.